# Can I force CALayer to use setNeedsDisplayInRect: rather than setNeedsDisplay for custom property

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

I have custom property and I override `+needsDisplayForKey:` to return YES for this property.
My `-drawInContext:` method is pretty complex while the rectangle affected by my custom property is pretty small. I'd like to optimize it.

The solution I'm thinking about is to implement custom setter where I'll explicitly mark affected rectangle to display. One thing I'm not sure about is that such implementation would be equal to original one and will handle implicit animation. *(rdar://11008555)*

Will it be equal or there is a better solution? (Target platforms are 10.6+)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to draw on a portion of a `CALayer`. Core Animation layers are implemented as textures on OpenGL surfaces. When you implement custom drawing, what essentially happens is that your drawing commands are used to build a bitmap and then that bitmap is set as the texture for the `CALayer`'s OpenGL surface.

What you could do is manage a bitmap cache (using an `NSImage` or `CGContext`) for the layer yourself. That way you could just modify the part of the bitmap that requires redrawing, then draw the image to the layer using `setContents:`.

Comment: CALayers cache their drawn content in the `contents` property. It's perfectly reasonable to expect that `UIView`'s `-drawInRect:` is implemented by first drawing the previous cached contents into the new context before invoking this method (assuming the given rect doesn't cover the entire view).

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible. You'd essentially be doing the same thing here for the `CALayer`. `CALayer` is much more lightweight than `UIView` or `NSView` so you need to manage it yourself.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood what you had said: I cannot just check intersection of dirty rect by using `CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(aContext)` to select what prtions to draw as I could do for NSView [(Draw Minimally)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/AdvancedDrawing/AdvancedDrawing.html). Instead I should either always perform all drawing routines or cache the result of previous invocation this method into NSImage and manually invalidate and update portions using `CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(aContext)`. right?

Comment: @Kentzo: Sorry, my comment was based around iOS (specifically, `UIView`'s `-drawInRect:` method). I can only guess that you can accomplish something similar in OS X. And anyway, I was just pointing out that you can still achieve partial redraw behavior in CoreAnimation by caching the previously drawn image until after you've drawn your new image. I don't know anything about the actual question, which is if invalidating rects outside of `+needsDisplayForKey:` preserves animation support.